# Fourier transform without Gibbs oscillations

Tags: fourier-analysis, discrete-mathematics, fourier-series

Is there a way to obtain the Fourier transform of a function (e.g., sinc) without the Gibbs phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gibbs phenomenon is a property of the Fourier transform. Any way to produce the correct Fourier coefficients will show the Gibbs phenomenon. You can produce a different series, whose partial sums are not the partial sums of the Fourier series, to reduce or eliminate the Gibbs phenomenon. One such method is to use the [Lanczos sigma factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LanczosSigmaFactor.html).